# Returning an object after reduce function

Tags: javascript

Im trying to use reduce in combination with the spread operator to practice. 
I have an array that i wish to convert into an object. I tried doing this, but my reduce function only returns the last value of the array. I wish this reducer function to add on to the array.

My try :

```
const arr = ['1' , '4' , '3' , '5' , '3'];

let obj;
arr.reduce((acc ,val) => {
    obj = {...acc , [val]:val};
},{});

console.log(obj)
```

Why do i only get the last value? and not the entire array to an object?

Comment: Why are you assigning inside a `reduce`? `arr.reduce((acc ,val) => ({...acc, [val]: val}), {});` returns the new object you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reduce callback expects a `return` if expressed like you did. In your scenario, **nothing** is returned from your reduce callback, because `obj` is assigned but never returned, hence `acc` in the second iteration is not defined and `obj` is assigned in each cycle, resulting in the last element of `arr` spread to an object.

If you want to do that in a single line, you can also avoid assigning to `obj`, by just using reduce as intended, by spreading progressively to a brand new object. The value returned by `reduce` will be assigned to `obj`.

```js
const arr = ['1' , '4' , '3' , '5' , '3'];

let obj = arr.reduce((acc, val) => ({...acc, [val]: val}), {});
//                                                         ^--- initial value
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you did not return the balue from reduce

```js
const arr = ['1' , '4' , '3' , '5' , '3'];

let obj = arr.reduce((acc ,val) => {
    const obj = {...acc , [val]:val};
    return obj;
},{});

console.log(obj)
```

or simplified

```js
const arr = ['1', '4', '3', '5', '3'];
const obj = arr.reduce((acc, val) => ({ ...acc,[val]: val}), {});
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the new value of the accumulator out of the reducing function

```js
const arr = ['1' , '4' , '3' , '5' , '3'];

const obj = arr.reduce((acc ,val) => {
    return {...acc , [val]:val};
},{});

console.log(obj);
```

You can shorten that a bit further by returning the object literal wrapped in parentheses. See [returning object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals)

```
const arr = ['1' , '4' , '3' , '5' , '3'];

const obj = arr.reduce((acc ,val) => ({...acc , [val]:val}), {});

console.log(obj);
```